# Did I see the Formosat-5 F9 2nd stage nozzle vibrate at about 2Hz at SECO-1?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, nozzle

Did I see the F9 2nd stage nozzle vibrate at about 2Hz at SECO-1? It looked like the bottom of the bell vibrated in an elliptical shape. Did I imagine that? Has this happened before?

$\hskip 3.4 cm$It's just after `T+ 09:17`, playing at half speed:

$\hskip 3.5 cm$[image]

Comment: Watching the video the vibration happens right at SECO and it looks like it is a transient as the engine shuts down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This video from the Iridium-2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ei3nGWD4d5A) launch definitely shows a squash-and-stretch oscillation at SECO-1, after 23:45 into the video.

I see a [less distinct version of the same oscillation in CRS-11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JuZBOUMsYws) after 29:00.

The Merlin vacuum engine nozzle is a quite thin shell (getting down to 1/64" thickness according to one member of this SE) and subject to substantial forces from the exhaust; it would be surprising if it didn't vibrate and flutter a bit depending on the throttle state.

[image: Merlin Vac nozzle extension]